# Puppeteer scraping; adding text to search bar returning error

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm learning to use puppeteer but I'm running into trouble. I'm trying to create a program which takes in a date and finds a famous persons whose birthday is on that date. I have this code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
try {
    (async () => {
        console.log('here');
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.famousbirthdays.com/');
        console.log('me');
        await page.type(document.querySelector('input'), '11-16-1952');
        console.log('you clicked');
        await page.click(document.querySelector('button'));
        console.log('Here');
        await page.waitForSelector(
            document.querySelector('div[class="list_page"]')
        );

        let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let name = document.querySelector('div[class="name"').textContent;

            return { name };
        });

        console.log(data);

        browser.close();
    })();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Im not understand why I'm getting errors at the page.type line? I get an error and cant reach that log of "you clicked". If I read the documentation correctly, .click can take in a selector and text to type into it so I'm pretty sure im using it correctly. I checked on the browser console and document.querySelector('input') does pull up the element I want(the search bar). Any advice is appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Your problem here is that `document` is only available in the browser context, (inside a `page.evaluate` for example). meaning `await page.type(document...` <- this is a no go. You can feed it css-selectors directly instead: `await page.type('input', '11-16-1952');`

Comment: @ippi thank you!! I see now, I got it working up until page.waitForSelector! Now it just stays there forever haha. I'll see if I can find whats going on. Thanks again!